# Question on a permutation of the roots of a Galois number field, dihedral over the rationals

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

The polynomial $f(x) = x^6 - 7x^5 + 21x^4 - 41x^3 + 63x^2 - 63x + 27$ defines a Galois extension $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. The Galois group of the extension $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is dihedral, and depending on your notation is $D_6$ or $D_3$.

(Aside: in fact I generated the polynomial by defining $g_1(\tau) = \eta(\tau/3)/\eta(\tau)$, where $\eta(\tau)$ is the Dedekind eta function, and letting $w = g_1(\tau)^2$ where $\tau = (-1 + \sqrt{-23})/2$ and taking the minimum polynomial of $w$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact $w$ generates the Hilbert class field $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Suppose that the roots of $f(x)$ are written $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_6$. Also suppose that they are ordered such that $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3, r_4$ and $r_5, r_6$ are complex conjugate pairs.

An automorphism in $G =$ Gal$(H/\mathbb{Q})$ defines a permutation on the roots.

My question is this: is there a $\sigma \in G$ which as a permutation on the roots is given by $(r_1 r_2)(r_3 r_4)(r_5 r_6)$.

Comment: I fed it into a graphing program, and it looks like the polynomial is positive for all real $x$, so, no real roots.

Comment: Yes, the roots are approximately:

[1.2849201454990266329556999790597843244 - 0.24186999128647610163946329705918097326*I, 1.2849201454990266329556999790597843244 + 0.24186999128647610163946329705918097326*I, 2.2548776662466927600495088963585286919 - 0.42445224584391909433345158075420027900*I, 2.2548776662466927600495088963585286919 + 0.42445224584391909433345158075420027900*I, -0.039797811745719393005208875418313016315 - 1.7315935245259645748258041542679657077*I, -0.039797811745719393005208875418313016315 + 1.7315935245259645748258041542679657077*I]

So no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

The complex conjugate is such automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I present here two different answers. The first is how I see it. The second is how another mathematicians sees it, even after I explained my answer and followed it with a four hour discussion. I wonder if anyone else is convinced by the second answer?

Answer 1: Let $\tau$ be complex conjugation. It is well known and easy to see that $\tau(H) = H$. Clearly $\tau$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus it is a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of $H$. By definition it is therefore an element of Gal$(H/\mathbb{Q})$ and by definition it has the required action on the roots of $f$.

Answer 2: If complex conjugation were a Galois automorphism of $H$ then $H$ would have a totally real subfield. As it does not (admitted), it is not a Galois automorphism.

$H$ is the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$. Given an ordering of the roots $r_1, \ldots, r_6$ there is a map $\phi : H \to \mathbb{C}^6$ which is defined by $x \pmod{f} \mapsto (r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_6)$.

An automorphism in $G =$ Gal$(H/\mathbb{Q})$ induces a permutation on the roots. However, there is no automorphism in $G$ which maps $(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6)$ to $(r_2, r_1, r_4, r_3, r_6, r_5)$. Instead an automorphism that permutes the roots so that $r_1$ is sent to $r_2$ and vice versa will send $(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6)$ to something like $(r_2, r_1, r_6, r_5, r_4, r_3)$.

A demonstration follows using the favourite computer algebra system of this mathematician, which confirms his claim.

Are there two fundamentally different definitions of the terms used in my question in the literature? Specifically, what is meant by a permutation of the roots given by a Galois automorphism?

Comment: What makes you admit that $H$ has no totally real subfield?

Comment: I mean no degree 3 totally real subfield. Obviously $\mathbb{Q}$ is a totally real subfield of $H$.

Comment: OK, what makes you admit that $H$ has no degree 3 totally real subfield?

Comment: Well one reason is Pari/GP can compute the Galois subfields of the field defined by f, and none of them have defining polynomials with all roots real.

Comment: So, the numbers $r_1+r_2$, $r_3+r_4$, and $r_5+r_6$ aren't the three real roots of some cubic with integer coefficients?

Comment: No. The value $r_1 + r_2$ is a root of $x^3 - 7x^2 + 18x - 17$. The value $r_3 + r_4$ is a root of $x^3 - 7x^2 + 15x - 17$ and $r_5 + r_6$ is a root of $x^3 - 7x^2 + 12x + 1$. (Given the ordering of roots given by the numerical approximations above, anyway.)

Comment: I think the following is a proof that $H$ has no cubic totally real subfield. If it did then that field cannot be Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ since this would imply that $D_6$ had a normal subgroup of order $2$, which it does not. Thus $H$ must be the normal closure of any totally real cubic subfield. But this is impossible since the normal closure would be given by adjoining the three (real) roots of the defining cubic to $\mathbb{Q}$. This would have degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$ and all its elements would be real. But $H$ is totally complex.

Comment: A field fixed by complex conjugation must be real, but it does not need to be totally real. For example $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\zeta_3)$ has two complex embeddings into $\mathbb C$ even though the field itself is real.

Comment: I agree with you, but some mathematicians don't seem to accept that there is such a thing as a real number field. For example, is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ real or not? It seems to be a matter of language. But it seems to matter here because a serious mathematician insists that there is no Galois automorphism which acts as complex conjugation on all the roots in my example. In your example, they would simply say your field has one real embedding, not that it is a real field.

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ is a real number field - by which I mean an abstract number field that has been embedded into $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-2)$ is an abstract field which can be embedded into $\mathbb C$ in three ways, one of which real. Here there is an ambiguity because the extension is not Galois. In the case where a number field $K$ is Galois, any embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb C$ will be an automorphism of $K$. Either way, if a number field is Galois and has complex roots, then its Galois group contains an element corresponding to complex conjugation. There is no ambiguity there.

Comment: Even if you shun the language of a real number field, it is still false that $H$ having an action of complex conjugation means it has an index 2 totally real subfield.

Comment: An embedding of $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ into $\mathbb{C}$ isn't an automorphism of $K$. An automorphism is an isomorphism from a field to itself. An embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ is nothing more than an injection, or if you prefer, an isomorphism onto its image.

In my example in the question, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ is a Galois number field. Yet there is no single automorphism in the Galois group which corresponds to complex conjugation. The automorphism is different depending on which embedding you choose. The situation would be as you say if the number field were abelian, but it isn't.

Comment: In summary, in the alternative language, if $H$ is a Galois number field and has a single Galois automorphism that acts as complex conjugation regardless of embedding, then it does have a totally real subfield.

Comment: An embedding of a *Galois* number field $K$ into $\mathbb C$ restricts to an automorphism on its image. I think you're being pedantic here. Fine, there is no abstract element that corresponds to complex conjugation in every embedding. But you don't need this. For your question, it is enough that there is an element that corresponds to complex conjugation in some embedding.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you. I'm simply noting that this language apparently isn't accepted by all mathematicians.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is <s>right</s> likely as confused as I was.

Since your extension is Galois, there are $6$ polynomials $P_1,\ldots,P_6$ with rational coefficients 
such that $f(T)$ factors in $\Bbb Q[X]/(f(X))$ as $\prod (T-P_i(X))$.
Those polynomials will permute the roots, and with composition modulo $f$, they form a group isomorphic
to the Galois group, but we have to be careful because their actions on the roots isn't the action of the Galois group itself.

You can actually explicitly recover the polynomials from the roots by looking at what combinations of them are "rational".

We know that the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_3$ so it will have $3$ "transpositions" that will separate the $6$ roots in $3$ pairs.

For example, $\{\{r_1,r_2\},\{r_3,r_6\},\{r_4,r_5\}\}$ is a "rational" object because $(X-(r_1+r_2))(X-(r_3+r_6))(X-(r_4+r_5))$ (and similarly for the products) have rational coefficients, so this partition is invariant by the Galois group. Since its element have only $3$ conjugates, they are fixed by a subgroup $\{id,\tau\}$ of $G$. Hence the Galois group (as a subgroup of the permutation of the complex roots) contains the permutation $\tau = (r_1,r_2)(r_3,r_6)(r_4,r_5)$

Lo and behold, if you interpolate the polynomial that go through the $6$ points in the graph of $\tau$, you obtain
$P_{(1,2)(3,6)(4,5)} = \frac 1 9 (27-21x+14x²-9x^3+4x^4-x^5)$.

You can look for the other two transpositions and you will obtain

$P_{(1,5)(2,6)(3,4)} = \frac 19 (63-63x+41x^2-21x^3+7x^4-x^5)$
$P_{(1,3)(2,4)(5,6)} = \frac 19 (297-483x+350x^2-204x^3+88x^4-16x^5)$

And you obtain the last two elements by making compositions and interpolating (or composing the polynomials then looking modulo $f$)

$P_{(1,4,6)(2,3,5)} = -12+25x-19x^2+11x^3-5x^4+x^5$
$P_{(1,6,4)(2,5,3)} = -24+37x-26x^2+15x^3-6x^4+x^5$

From this polynomial group acting on the roots, 
we recover the Galois group by taking the transpose of the group law of the polynomials (if you write the composition table, you go from one to the other by transposing it).

Say we fix a root $r_1$ and we decide to call $\sigma_i$ and $P_i$ the automorphism and the polynomial sending $r_1$ to $r_i$.
Then $\sigma_i(r_j) = \sigma_i(P_j(r_1)) = P_j(\sigma_i(r_1)) = P_j(r_i)$.

And $(\sigma_i \circ \sigma_j)(r_1) = \sigma_i (P_j(r_1)) = (P_j \circ P_i) (r_1)$ so the map
$\sigma_i \mapsto P_i^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of groups (but not of group actions on the roots !!)

Finally we can check that $\sigma_2(r_3) = P_3(r_2) = r_4$, which is enough to conclude that $\sigma_2$ acts as complex conjugation.

Comment: The Galois group is not abelian, hence I don't think you can't just compose the polynomials modulo f. As I understand it, that only works for abelian Galois groups.

Comment: I don't see why not. Composition is not commutative.

Comment: Similarly I don't think you can apply the polynomial to all the roots to see how it permutes them. If that were the case then for any $\sigma$ in the Galois group I would have $\sigma(P(r_i)) = P(\sigma(r_i))$ which would effectively mean all the elements of the Galois group commuted.

Comment: You might be right about being able to compose. I'm not sure on that. Either way I don't dispute these are the correct polynomials, since it is easy to check them.

Comment: you have to be careful, because $P_{\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2} = P_{\sigma_2} \circ P_{\sigma_1}$ (the order of composition is reversed). By definition, if $\sigma(r_1) = P_\sigma (r_1)$, then $\sigma(P(r_1)) = P(P_\sigma(r_1))$ forall polynomial $P$, but ONLY for the root $r_1$. I must say I'm also a bit confused there lol

Comment: Don't think of $\sigma$ as a polynomial, just as an automorphism. Then for any of your polynomials $P$ we have $\sigma(P(r_i)) = P(\sigma(r_i))$ because $\sigma$ is an automorphism. Thus it is clear that $P$ cannot give the action of a Galois automorphism on a root $r_i$. If it did, the group would by definition be abelian.

Comment: I think that's equivalent to what I'm saying. Given one of your polynomials $P$ you can't simply evaluate $P$ at each of the roots to see how it permutes the roots. Clearly evaluating $P(x)$ at an arbitrary root $r_i$ is not the same as the action of any Galois automorphism $\phi$.

Comment: Yeah the thing is, if $\sigma(r_1) = P_\sigma(r_1)$ then $\sigma(r_2)$ is NOT $P_\sigma(r_2)$, but it is $Q(r_2)$ for some conjugate $Q$ of $P_\sigma$  (this is so confusing ;_;).

Comment: Well, if we use your $P_{\sigma_2\circ \sigma_1} = P_{\sigma_1}\circ P_{\sigma_2}$ we should at least be able to work out the action of the polynomials on all the roots. And then we should be able to confirm if there is or isn't one that acts as complex conjugation.

Comment: oh I forgot that this WAS the question. Say we "focus" on $r_1$ for applying those rules. $\sigma_{(1,2)(3,6)(4,5)}(r_3) = \sigma_{(1,2)(3,6)(4,5)}(P_{(1,3)(2,4)(5,6)} (r_1)) = (P_{(1,3)(2,4)(5,6)} (r_2)) = r_4$, so yes, complex conjugation IS an element of the Galois group after all...

Comment: Yep, I concur. I checked with your polynomials (numbered P1 -- P6 in the order you give them) that $P_i(P_2(r_1)) = \overline{P_i(r_1)}$ for all $i$.

I am almost certain this is what my friend was doing wrong.

Now the only remaining question is if his favourite CAS is doing it correctly! Certainly if I ask it for the Galois group of f as a set of permutations on the roots (according to the fixed ordering it chooses), then complex conjugation is in there. But he seemed to be getting it to do the wrong thing with a different set of commands.

Comment: Of course this still depends on the embedding. Here we used the root $r_1$. If we had used $r_2$ instead, it would have been a different element of the Galois group that was complex conjugation. There is no single Galois automorphism that acts as complex conjugation for all embeddings.